# MYSQL select once for row with same values

Tags: mysql

MYSQL

My query so far will select different column_names from 2 tables and put under same column respectively.

In the selection from table c, I want to  select only once for the column with same value.

Example: c_id has 3 rows consist of value 52, select the first row encountered but skip the rest, the same goes for the row with value 41.

Is it possible to achieve by adjusting my current query or should I find another way?

```
 table m                    table c
 -----   -----  -----        -----   -----   -----
| m_id |m_date |m_siri|     | c_id | c_date| c_data|
 -----   -----  -----        -----   -----   -----
|   1  | 02-13 |  one |     |  52  | 01-12 |  xxx  |
 -----   -----  -----        -----   -----   -----
|   2  | 10-13 |  one |     |  41  | 11-13 |  yyy  |
 -----   -----  -----        -----   -----   -----
|   3  | 11-13 |  two |     |  41  | 12-13 |  zzz  |
 -----   -----  -----        -----   -----   -----
|   4  | 04-14 |  one |     |  52  | 08-14 |  eee  |
 -----   -----  -----        -----   -----   -----
|   5  | 01-15 |  two |     |  52  | 10-14 |  xxx  |
 -----   -----  -----        -----   -----   -----

(SELECT 
    m_ID AS id, m_date AS date 
FROM 
    m 
WHERE 
    m_siri='one' 
ORDER BY 
    m_date DESC LIMIT 2) 
UNION 
(SELECT 
    c_ID AS id, c_date AS date 
FROM 
    c 
ORDER BY 
    c_date DESC) 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` keyword for getting only once record from multiple.

```
(SELECT 
    m_ID AS id, m_date AS date 
FROM 
    m 
WHERE 
    m_siri='one' 
ORDER BY 
    m_date DESC LIMIT 2) 
UNION 
(SELECT 
    DISTINCT(c_ID) AS id, c_date AS date 
FROM 
    c 
ORDER BY 
    ch_date DESC) 
ORDER BY date DESC
```